# Word VBA code throwing Run-time error '9099': Make a selection first

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I have VBA code that has been running for several years. Recently a user in Mexico City ran my macro and got Run-time error 9099. I debugged on his PC remotely and found that it gets this error when the command ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges executes. I had to debug on his PC because I cannot reproduce the problem on my laptop. We are both using the same version of Word as we both work for the same multinational company so we have roughly the same hardware (Dell).

I can only find one reference to error 9099 on MSDN and it was related to a Close event, but it did not help me. The close Sub is as follows:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = gblnScreenUpdating
ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
Documents.Open (strTempFileName)
ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
Documents.Open (strWorkFileName)
ActiveWindow.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

The first Close is closing the final document on the network drive. The first open is opening a temporary file on the user's C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\OrderGuide folder created when I start the macro. I then close the temporary file and this is the command that throws the error. It is happening on several of the PCs in Mexico City but none in the U.S.

My folder C:\Users\user2\AppData\Roaming\OrderGuide is Read only (Only applies to files in folder). I haven't looked at the folder rights of the user in Mexico City PC but I assume it is the same.  We both have the same Word version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20648 32-bit. Our configurations are probably slightly different as I am classified a developer, BUT no users in US or India have reported this error.

I thought of a race condition between the Open and Close of the temporary file. If I put a DoEvents between the first Open and 2nd Close, that would not explain why it works on all PCs except a few in Mexico City. Could it be a Windows 10 or Office configuration issue? Our equipment is 64-bit PCs with 32-bit Office 365. Could the folder I created "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\OrderGuide" have different rights than I or others in the US have? I am grasping for straws as this code has worked for many, many years.

Any insight would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where and when do you run the code? Is it run on the server-side from a web application or service?

Comment: I would have to wonder what the point is of having Documents.Open (strTempFileName): ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges, since all you're doing is opening a document, which makes it the active document, then closing it without saving any auto-changes that might occur.

Comment: The macro is run from the user's local PC. No web application or service.

Comment: I agree about Opening then closing right away. Code is very old (20+ years) and I did not want to change it if it wasn't broken. Now it's broken. Commented out the Open and close of the strTempFileName and things appear to be working; not getting the error any more. However, I am really interested in "Run-time error 9099. Make selection first"  Any idea why this error now after 20+ years and why "Make a selection first."

Answer (score 0):

Try using specific document instances instead of dealing with the [ActiveDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.activedocument) property of the Word `Application` class which returns a `Document` object that represents the active document (the document with the focus). If there are no documents open, an error occurs. And it may be exactly your case.

Remember, the [Documents.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open) method opens the specified document and adds it to the `Documents` collection. And it returns a `Document` object, so you my keep it in the object reference and call the `Close` method where required.

Comment: Are you saying that when I use Documents.Open strTempFileName that I should probably use Documents(strTempFileName).Close wdDoNotSaveChanges? Assuming that strTempFileName were not there, then I would probably get an error. You are probably right, but does this explain error 9099 Make a selection first?

Comment: Try not to use any collections or properties for getting documents to close.  Try to keep them in a separate object and call it for closing.